# How can I get my Net application to start

Tags: c#, .net

I've been working with .Net for a few years now. I never had this problem before where the app fails to start. The following is a stack trace that I get.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.19044.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    clr.dll             : 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/derri/Desktop/NAS%20ETHER.appref-ms%7C

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\derri\Desktop\NAS ETHER.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Lock timeout exception.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [9/14/2022 7:25:14 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\derri\Desktop\NAS ETHER.appref-ms| has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [9/14/2022 7:27:14 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (LockTimeout)
        - Lock timeout exception.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.LockedFile.AcquireLock(String path, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean writer)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I thought I would uninstall the app and then re-install it to see if that would help but the launcher won't start for me to do that. Help guys if you can. Basically, the app displays a youtube playlist for instance Nas or Drake or Salt N Pepa music artist. Users can view a Wikipedia Bio of the artist, see artist photos or art on Google and play games like chess or solitaire.

This is a basic app and like I said I never had the problem before. I need some guidance if you can help I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: Looks like a file is locked. Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this app uses a webbrowser control created by a Company called Essential Objects.  So it allows me to view webpages. The problem starting may reside there but like I said I never had this problem until today

Comment: Yes I've restarted it with the same problem

Comment: Note I just wanted to see if the app would start in Visual Studio and it starts with no problem so I don't think it is the web browser control. Maybe what i should try is to put a new release of the app on my webserver and see if it will clear this up. I use Click Once

Comment: Looks like I found the problem. I have two virus protection apps, McAfee and I recently installed Avast. I uninstalled Avast and my .net apps worked. I may trying reinstalling Avast to duplicate the problem

Comment: For the next time: please put all relevant information in the question, [preferrable as text, not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Links to other sites are to be avoided as they might not be valid in the future making your question useless for future readers (remember: StackOverflow is a Q&A site).